# Pausing Spotify while YouTube is playing and starting it when YouTube stops

Tags: windows, itunes, music, youtube, spotify

Kind of a random request, but something that would be cool nonetheless; would there be anyway I could make Spotify (and possibly iTunes etc.) pause when I start playing a YouTube video, and then start again once the video ends or I pause it?

Is there any software that would allow me to do this? Or a language that would be able to accomplish this?

64bit Windows 7

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned. 64bit Windows 7

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: No, I did not solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I built mute.fm (http://www.mutefm.com/) to solve this problem.  It works with iTunes, Spotify, and many other music players and will mute/pause it for YouTube or any other video or foreground sound.

Comment: link broken @Jared_Sohn

Comment: link updated @Awesome_girl

Comment: Here is a link, for anyone who needs it.  I was a big fan, can't say if the application still works on recent Windows 10 though: http://www.markmajor.com/external/mutefm/mutefm_setup_0_9_14%202014-09-02%20%28Free%29.exe

Comment: any mac solutions?

Comment: for mac: https://github.com/kyleneideck/BackgroundMusic

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it, but I think it's doable.

First, add this wrapper to your spotify: https://github.com/johanlindquist/jahspotify. This will give you a REST interface to control playback.

Now, create a chrome (I assume that's what you're using. If not, there are probably similar options for other browsers as well) extension that works for everything on YouTube's domain and add this:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/8152814/1456578. Change the code to pause/resume spotify when a certain event happens on YT player.

As I'm intrested in a solution myself as well, I'll probably try it out sometime soon and will then update this answer with the results. Will most likely create/[use](https://www.google.com/?q=libspotify%20node) a lightweight node server to wrap Spotify instead, because Tomcat seems like an overkill and all you (I) actually need is the play/pause functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Opera GX now has this feature. The built in Music Player, which supports Spotify, YouTube Music and Apple Music, automatically pauses the music when you start watching a video and then automatically resumes when you finish.

Answer (score 0):

this python script works soo well on linux

https://gist.github.com/engelmarkus/fd81cd95775ffa365a58958e24829bd3

first make sure to install pulsectl `pip install pulsectl`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).